# How can I show correctly a progressbar and a label (that show the percentage) for filling multiple datasets?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

I need to update a DataGridView that has master detail part, I'm trying to use [this control](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215736/Master-Detail-Datagridview-in-Csharp) for the grid (I use 4 datasets for filling the grid).

**Question**: how can I add correctly a thread or more that will add to the grid these datasets and show the correct percentage and the same time the UI remain usable(responsive, not to become "not responding" for user)?

In every table I have about 10000 rows.

Please provide some code if possible, because I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

I tried like this, but I'm stuck at showing the user the correct percentage and correctly using the thread:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MasterDetail
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MasterControl masterDetail;

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            clearFields();
            loadData();
            //label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        void clearFields()
        {
            panelView.Controls.Clear();
            masterDetail = null;
            Refresh();
            masterDetail = new MasterControl(nwindDataSet);
            panelView.Controls.Add(masterDetail);
        }

        internal delegate void SetDataSourceDelegate();

        private void setDataSource()
        {
            if (this.masterDetail.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.masterDetail.BeginInvoke(new SetDataSourceDelegate(setDataSource));
            }
            else
            {
                createMasterDetailView();
            }
        }

        void loadData()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread =
                       new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate() { loadDataThread(); }));
            thread.Start();
        }

        void loadDataThread() 
        {
            orderReportsTableAdapter.Fill(nwindDataSet.OrderReports);
            invoicesTableAdapter.Fill(nwindDataSet.Invoices);
            employeesTableAdapter.Fill(nwindDataSet.Employees);
            customersTableAdapter.Fill(nwindDataSet.Customers);

            setDataSource();
        }

        void createMasterDetailView() 
        {
            masterDetail.setParentSource(nwindDataSet.Customers.TableName, "CustomerID");
            masterDetail.childView.Add(nwindDataSet.OrderReports.TableName, "Orders");
            masterDetail.childView.Add(nwindDataSet.Invoices.TableName, "Invoices");
            masterDetail.childView.Add(nwindDataSet.Employees.TableName, "Employees");

            typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,
  masterDetail, new object[] { true });

            foreach (DataGridView dvg in masterDetail.childView.childGrid)
            {
                typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,
dvg, new object[] { true });
            }

            masterDetail.childView.childGrid[2].RowTemplate.Height = 100;
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To have a detailed loading bar, The Master Detail class would need to have a callback for updating the completion amount. If it doesn't have one you would either need to modify the code to include one or just use a marquee style progress Bar to show that it is actually doing something. Alternatively, You could create a thread safe function for updating the progress bar and do so after each xxx.Fill() in the load Data Thread function.

Comment: Are you sure you should be solving this problem with multi-threading? Do you want the user to be able to do stuff while the application is loading the data? If not I would not even consider using multi-threading.

Comment: For me is more important that until it loads the 4 datasets the user sees the correct percentage and the app remain responsive. (by responsive i mean not to get "not responding" or freez. I though that until loads i will disable controls for the user. Is this a good approache? But i need some code how to do it with 4 datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better for you to use a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

It has an event called [WorkerReportsProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) that can help you create the progressbar you need.

Here is the sample code from msdn:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void startAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done.
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress.
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
```

you just need to add the proper computation of the percentage and you're done

Comment: Sorry, but how can I correctly calculate the percentage, because i have 4 datasets with different number of rows?

Comment: Sorry i was out for two days. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268364/need-make-progress-bar-when-data-is-reading-from-database) . What i would suggest is that you make the ProgressBar Indeterminate by setting the Style property to Marquee